# keystore lost Build Failed

Tags: build, keystore

hi all hope you're doing well.

I renamed the package name on android studio but not able to renew the lost keystore. code source asks for the old code keystore with an error:

- What went wrong:
  A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:packageGplayRelease'.

  > No value has been specified for property 'signingConfig.keyAlias'.

Comment: It seems that you have to delele and add again the keystore to your project. You can find more info [https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing)

Comment: @Carlos487 Thank you man. I will try once i’m at home. Now i’m at work. I will let you know what happened.

Comment: Solved. Thank you man. It works again 

Comment: I'm glad I could help please select the following answers as valid. It will help me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have to delele and add again the keystore to your project. You can find more information on the following link:

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

Comment: Thx. It was a great answer